# ReactJS how to select sibling and add or remove his className

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two inputs, one textarea and three labels. When input or textarea is in foucs, I want to add some class for some animation on label, but I can not select that specific label. Is there a way to do this?
here is a code

```
 <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
<div className="contact-form">
    <div className="contact-form_group">
        <label htmlFor="name" className={`contact-label name`}>
            Ime
        </label>
        <input onChange={this.handleChange} onFocus={this.handleFocus} id="name" value={this.state.name} className="contact-form_input" type="text" name="name" />
    </div>
    <div className="contact-form_group">
        <label htmlFor="email" className={`contact-label email`}>
            Email
        </label>
        <input onChange={this.handleChange} onFocus={this.handleFocus} id="email" value={this.state.email} className="contact-form_input" type="email" name="email" />
    </div>
    <div className="contact-form_group">
        <label htmlFor="message" className={`contact-label message`}>
            Message
        </label>
        <textarea className="contact-form_textarea" id="message" cols="3" rows="8" onChange={this.handleChange} onFocus={this.handleFocus} value={this.state.msg} name="msg" />
    </div>
    <Button className="button" type="submit" children="Send" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not worried about browser compatibility you could use the cutting edge CSS selector `:focus-within`

```
.contact-form > div:focus-within label
  color: red
```

BUT I wouldn't actually recommend that just yet. It's still part of the working draft and not widely supported.

In react, you could keep track of the active element's name and conditionally apply a class on render to the label. So `onFocus`/`onBlur` set `focusedElement`, eg

```
onFocus(e) {
  this.setState({focusedElement: e.currentTarget.getAttribute('name')})
}
```

and then in render do something like

`` className={`contact-label name ${this.state.focusedElement === 'name' ? 'focused' : ''}`} ``

Here's a working example -

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        focusedElement: null
      };
    }

    onFocus(e) {
      this.setState({
          focusedElement: e.currentTarget.getAttribute('name')
          });
      }

      onBlur(e) {
        this.setState({
          focusedElement: null
        });
      }

      render() {
        return ( <
          div >
          <
          label className = {
            this.state.focusedElement === 'name' ? 'focused' : ''
          } > Label For Name < /label> <
          input name = 'name'
          type = 'text'
          onFocus = {
            this.onFocus.bind(this)
          }
          onBlur = {
            this.onBlur.bind(this)
          }
          />

          <
          label className = {
            this.state.focusedElement === 'other' ? 'focused' : ''
          } > Label For Other Value < /label> <
          input name = 'other'
          type = 'text'
          onFocus = {
            this.onFocus.bind(this)
          }
          onBlur = {
            this.onBlur.bind(this)
          }
          /> < /
          div >
        );
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render( < TodoApp / > , document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
.focused {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I am worry about browser compatibility so I did it with changing the state, onFocus on some input I get name value from props so use that name to change state and add class to specific label..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add a class to let your css if the input/textarea it's on focus. CSS can handle this for you.

```
input:focus { 
    background-color: 'red'; // or do some animation here
}
```

Comment: I think the user wanted to add a class to the label, not the input/textarea

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't have a very efficient way of handling nested child components in a way similar to this.  The best way to handle styling for specific nodes/children would be to use classes and then css to style appropriately.

In your case you would do something like this:

```
.contact-form_input:focus {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

If you wanted to add some styling on hover or some additional animation it would be done in a similar way (using CSS):

```
.contact-form_input:hover {
    background-color: #aaa;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s;
    animation: fadein 0.5s;
}
```

It would not be appropriate to incorporate JQuery with ReactJS as other posters have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

There is a React synthetic event for onFocus. You could update the state as the focus changes and change each inputs className.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/308871/)

```
        <div className="form__group">
                <label htmlFor="input1" className={focus === "input1" ? "focused__input" : "input"}>Input 1</label>
                <input name="input1" onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)} onFocus={this._onFocus.bind(this, "input1")}/>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define ref to that label and on focus you can get the value of that lable using

// Define ref to label

// Get label object on focus change event and update the class accordingly for label
   var object = this.refs.labelName;

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery `npm install --save jquery`

and use jquery's addClass method.

```
import $ from 'jquery'
 .....
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <div className='contact-form'>
      <div className='contact-form_group'>
        <label htmlFor='name' className={`contact-label name`} id='l1' >Ime</label>
        <input onChange={this.handleChange}
               onFocus={()=>{$(#l1).addClass('classNameYouWantToAdd')}} id='name' 
               value={this.state.name} 
               className='contact-form_input' 
               type='text' name='name'/>
      </div>
      <div className='contact-form_group'>
        <label htmlFor='email' className={`contact-label email`} id='l2'>Email</label>
        <input onChange={this.handleChange} 
               onFocus={()=>{$(#l2).addClass('classNameYouWantToAdd')}} id='name' 
               id='email' value={this.state.email} className='contact-form_input' type='email' name='email'/>
      </div>
      <div className='contact-form_group'>
        <label htmlFor='message' className={`contact-label message`}>Message</label>
        <textarea className='contact-form_textarea' id='message' cols='3' rows='8' onChange={this.handleChange} onFocus={this.handleFocus} value={this.state.msg} name='msg'></textarea>
      </div>
      <Button className='button' type='submit' children='Send' />
    </div>
  </form>
```